# Remove a attribute from the IXMLDOMDocument2 (Delphi)

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

I have the following XML:

```
<TABLE Table="STUDENT">
    <FIELD fieldName="ID" fldType="INT"/>
    <FIELD fieldName="NAME" fldType="STRING"/>
    <FIELD fieldName="REDUNDANTFIELD" fldType="STRING"/>
    <FIELD fieldName="PHONENUMBER" fldType="STRING"/>
</TABLE>
```

I want to remove the row where the attribute of the fieldname is "REDUNDANTFIELD" .. How can i do it ?

Expected output after the row is deleted

```
<TABLE Table="STUDENT">
    <FIELD fieldName="ID" fldType="INT"/>
    <FIELD fieldName="NAME" fldType="STRING"/>
    <FIELD fieldName="PHONENUMBER" fldType="STRING"/>
</TABLE>
```

Can anyone help me to proceed with the following function ?

```
function RemoveAttributeRRow(myXML: IXMLDOMDocument2): IXMLDOMDocument2;
begin
  // my code here
  Result:= ???;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure RemoveAttributeRRow(doc: IXMLDOMDocument2);
var
  node: IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  node := Doc.selectSingleNode('//FIELD[@fieldName=''REDUNDANTFIELD'']');
  if node<>nil then
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
end;

procedure TForm14.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  m: IXMLDOMDocument2;
begin
  m := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  m.load('c:\work\1.xml');
  RemoveAttributeRRow(m);
  m.save('c:\work\2.xml');
end;
```

Comment: I have 2 comments: `(1)` Id make another parameter in `RemoveAttributeRRow(doc: IXMLDOMDocument2; fieldName: string)` to be more generic. `(2)` change `if node=nil then exit;` -> `if Assigned(node) then node.parentNode.removeChild(node);`.

Comment: @kobik: It seems to be obvious and anyone can adjust it for his own needs (create parameters for node name, attribute name, attribute value, ...). The only not 100% obvious thing here is syntax for XPath expression. So i think any additions will not help anyone, but make XPath little harder to read/understand.

Comment: @user: If suggested answer is solution, then you should accept it (click mark under counter).